# Scaling the image and setting in Image View reduces image quality and squeezes it

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

I am tying to make a custom camera and after taking picture I am setting it in image view in the same activity as in which I am setting camera. I have been successful in taking the photos but before setting the image in image view I have to scale it which reduces the image quality. Is there any way to show the real image instead of scaling it?

**My images are as below First one is real view of camera which is surface view:**
[image: This is the real view of camera]

**After Taking photo it becomes:**

[image: The real camera image]

The code I am using is:

```
Camera.PictureCallback picture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            surface_view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            setupImageDisplay(data);

        }
    };

    private void setupImageDisplay(byte[] data) {
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        photo = scaleDown(photo, true);//scaling down bitmap
        imageview_photo.setImageBitmap(photo); //setting bitmap in imageview

    }

    public Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage, boolean filter) {
        int screenWidth = width;
        int screenHeight = height;

        Bitmap scaled;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // Notice that width and height are reversed
            scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, screenHeight, screenWidth, filter);
            int w = scaled.getWidth();
            int h = scaled.getHeight();
            // Setting post rotate to 90

            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

            if (camera_id == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                float[] mirrorY = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
                matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

                mtx.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
            }
            mtx.postRotate(90);
            // Rotating Bitmap
            realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, filter);
        } else {// LANDSCAPE MODE
            //No need to reverse width and height
            scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, screenHeight, screenWidth, filter);
            int w = scaled.getWidth();
            int h = scaled.getHeight();
            // Setting post rotate to 90

            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();

            if (camera_id == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                float[] mirrorY = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
                matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

                mtx.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);
            }
            mtx.postRotate(180);
            // Rotating Bitmap
            realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, filter);
        }
        return realImage;
    }
```

After taking photo the image is like squeezed is there any way that image remains the same after scaling?

Comment: Try to use Glide library, it will autoscale your images.

Comment: @MaximeLiege but in glide dont you have to give the url of the image? In this case I am using simple bitmap

Comment: No you can give it Drawables aswell

Comment: Okay I will give it bitmap lets see what happens Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file which is temporary file and stores the thumbnail size of the image. You can make a POJO like this to store both images. You can display the smaller one and use the original file to keep high quality.

```
public class Image {
File fullSize;
File Thumbnail;

public Image(File fullSize, File thumbnail) {
    this.fullSize = fullSize;
    Thumbnail = thumbnail;
}

public File getFullSize() {
    return fullSize;
}

public void setFullSize(File fullSize) {
    this.fullSize = fullSize;
}

public File getThumbnail() {
    return Thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(File thumbnail) {
    Thumbnail = thumbnail;
}
```

}

Comment: Should I store the file of image within application?

Comment: Use permission to access the file storage of the phone. And save the files there, you should also save the path of image.

Comment: but I dont want to store that image anywhere in the phone is that possible with this?

Comment: Yea.. you can do it. You can create 2 different bitmaps as well. One with no scale down and one with scale down. And keep the objects of your bitmap stored in your app.

Comment: Thanks I will try it and will let you know :)